# AMP Project doesn´t excecute the PHP code as Form or even as echo

Tags: php, amp-html

I have a website AMP project and I wanted to use PHP for forms.

On the webpage form which has a post method returns no action in the backend code.
So I think that the data inn´t transfered.

---

edit on answer:

My form code is:

```
        <form method="POST" class="sit-form" action-xhr="ampsend.php" data-form-title="contactForm">
                    <div class="sit-row">
                        <div submit-success="" class="sit-col-lg-12 sit-col-md-12 sit-col-sm-12">
                            <template data-form-alert="" type="amp-mustache">success!
                            </template>
                        </div>
                        <div submit-error="" class="sit-col-lg-12 sit-col-md-12 sit-col-sm-12">
                            <template data-form-alert="" type="amp-mustache">failed! {{error}}</template>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dragArea sit-row">
                        <div class="sit-col-md-12 field sit-col-sm-12">
                            <input type="hidden" name="firstnameHidden" value="Firstname"
                                   id="firstnameHidden"
                                   data-form-field="">
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" data-form-field="Name"
                                   required="required" class="field-input display-4" value=""
                                   id="firstname">
                        </div>
                        <div class="sit-col-md-12 field sit-col-sm-12">
                            <input type="hidden" name="lastnameHidden" value="Lastname"
                                   id="lastnameHidden"
                                   data-form-field="">
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" data-form-field="Name"
                                   class="field-input display-4" required="required" value=""
                                   id="lastname">
                        </div>
                        <div class="sit-col-md-12 field sit-col-sm-12">
                            <input type="hidden" name="emailHidden" value="Email" id="emailHidden"
                                   data-form-field="">
                            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" data-form-field="Email"
                                   required="required" class="field-input display-4" value=""
                                   id="email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="sit-col-md-12 sit-col-sm-12 field">
                            <input type="hidden" name="messageHidden" value="Message"
                                   id="messageHidden"
                                   data-form-field="">
                            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" data-form-field="Message"
                                      class="field-input display-4" required="required" value=""
                                      id="message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div data-for=""
                             class="sit-col-md-12 sit-section-btn sit-pt-4 align-center sit-col-sm-12 field">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary display-4">
                                send
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

The file_put_contents of the POST by clicking on submit is:

```
a:8:{
s:15:"firstnameHidden";
s:9:"Firstname";
s:9:"firstname";
s:8:"TestName";
s:14:"lastnameHidden";
s:8:"Lastname";
s:8:"lastname";
s:12:"TestLastname";
s:11:"emailHidden";
s:5:"Email";
s:5:"email";
s:13:"test@test.com";
s:13:"messageHidden";
s:7:"Message";
s:7:"message";
s:11:"testMessage";}
```

So does it work correctly? because as return I get the "failed!" - message from the AMP template.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot execute PHP code on the displaying document. PHP is serving the data to show through an `POST` on the displaying web document as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729564/amp-form-to-work-with-php).

Comment: ok, thats mayby why an include is working but even when I try to handle a form with POST method I didn´t get any reaction of the code? --> So isn´t it possible to have a button type"submit" to send a POST request to the server?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to check if PHP is running ,and check what data was posted via form - was write everything to text file.

```
$serializedData = serialize($_POST);
file_put_contents('your_file_name.txt', $serializedData);
```

Open file and see what data was pass. If you want display message after form was submitted and pass some date like name or email. You need to use amp-mustache. And and return JSON form PHP to pass it back to your AMP page.

For example in your PHP file:
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array( 'name' => $_POST['name]' ));

Of course don't forget to put appropriate CORS headers in PHP or you .htaccess file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this... I tryed the outputh with my code and edited the question. What would you say about it?